# Azure Repos API Commits - GetChanges returning empty list

Tags: azure, api

I have an Azure build pipeline with the following powershell task running on the agent to get the commits of my PR:

```
$id = $(System.PullRequest.PullRequestId)
$uri = "$(System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri)NPI/_apis/git/repositories/$(Build.Repository.ID)/pullRequests/$id/commits?api-version=5.1"
Write-Host "Getting all commits for PR" $id ":" $uri
$J = Invoke-WebRequest -URI $uri -Headers @{
    Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"
    } | ConvertFrom-Json
```

And then loop through the reply like this:

```
foreach ($c in $J.value)
{
  $id = $c.commitId
  $uri = "$(System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri)NPI/_apis/git/repositories/$(Build.Repository.ID)/commits/$id/changes?api-version=5.1"
  Write-Host "Getting details for commit" $id ":" $uri
  $J = Invoke-WebRequest -URI $uri -Headers @{
    Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"
    } | ConvertFrom-Json
  Write-Host $J
}
```

The log file of the Azure task contains this:

```
Getting all commits for PR 1026 : https://dev.azure.com/xxx/xxx/_apis/git/repositories/xxx/pullRequests/1026/commits?api-version=5.1
Getting details for commit xxx : https://dev.azure.com/xxx/xxx/_apis/git/repositories/xxx/commits/xxx/changes?api-version=5.1
@{changeCounts=; changes=System.Object[]}
```

As you can see, there are no changes listed. However, if I click on the logged url for getting the commit details, I get a non-empty list. What's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Oops, turns out it does actually work but the Write-Host output is broken.

This runs fine:

```
foreach ($cc in $J.changes)
{
  Write-Host $cc.item.path
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a variable to store it before convert to json. This is work correctly to me.

```
"$($env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONCOLLECTIONURI)$env:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECTID/_apis/git/repositories/$($pipeline.repository.id)/commits/$(Build.BuildId)/changes?api-version=5.0"
Write-Host $commitUrl

$rsCommit = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $commitUrl -Headers @{
    Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"}
Write-Host "CommitInfo = $($rsCommit | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)"
```